# Как передать данные в recyclerView из активности?

Tags: java, android

Только начинаю погружаться в android, в связи с этим возникают некие сложности. У меня в проекте есть recyclerView с обектами Note, при нажатии на которые я открываю активность с информацией об этой "записке", конкретно название и основной текст. У меня реализовано подгрузка названия и текста в активность, при ее открытии, но я не понимаю, как я могу сохранить отредактированную заметку и отобразить обновленные название и текст на "главном" экране.

Код recyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

Context mContext;
List<Note> mData;
Dialog mDialog;
//NotesFragment notesFragment;
int selected;



public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Note> mData) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = mData;
    //this.notesFragment = notesFragment;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View v;
    v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.notes_list_item,viewGroup,false);
    final MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);


    //---------------------Инициализация диалогового окна и его вызов по кнопке----------------------------------------------------------
    mDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_note);
    Button yes_button = mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_yes_btn);
    Button no_button = mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_no_btn);

    viewHolder.item_note.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Test Click" + String.valueOf(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mDialog.show();
            selected = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

            return false;
        }
    });

    yes_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                deleteItem(selected);
                mDialog.cancel();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                //   for (int i = 0; i < mData.size(); i++) {
                //      mData[i]
                //  }
            }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                Log.e("Error","\n ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException length=10 index=-1 \n Опять -1, но как ???");
            }
        }
    });

    no_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDialog.cancel();
        }
    });
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Редактор заметки?

viewHolder.item_note.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,NoteActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Title",viewHolder.tv_Name.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("Text",viewHolder.tv_Text.getText().toString());
        mContext.startActivity(intent);




    }
});






    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.tv_Name.setText(mData.get(position).getName());
    holder.tv_Date.setText(mData.get(position).getDate());
    holder.button.setBackgroundResource(mData.get(position).getFavourite());
    holder.tv_Text.setText(mData.get(position).getText());




}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private LinearLayout item_note;
    private TextView tv_Name;
    private TextView tv_Date;
    private Button button;
    private TextView tv_Text;



    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        item_note = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_item);
        tv_Name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_note);
        tv_Date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_note);
        button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.favorite_btn_note);
        tv_Text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_note);
    }
}

//Добавление данных
public void addItem(int position, Note note){
    mData.add(position, note);
    //Мы можем вызвать
    super.notifyItemInserted(position);
}

//Удаление данных
public void deleteItem(int position){
    mData.remove(position);

    //То же самое с методом
    super.notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mData.size());
  //  notesFragment.decreasePosition();
    NotesFragment.decreasePosition();


}
```

}

Код NoteActivity.java

public class NoteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private String NoteTitle;
private String NoteText;
EditText textNote;
EditText titleNote;
Button saveBtn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note);

    saveBtn = findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
   // saveBtn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
    //        AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.save), null, null, null); --иконочка

    titleNote = findViewById(R.id.title_note);
    textNote = findViewById(R.id.main_text_note);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    NoteTitle = intent.getStringExtra("Title");
    NoteText = intent.getStringExtra("Text");

    titleNote.setText(NoteTitle);
    textNote.setText(NoteText);




    saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          //  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
          //  startActivity(intent);  -- создание новой мейн активности


            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("TitleGet",titleNote.getText().toString());
            finish();
        }
    });




}
```

}

Повторюсь - нужно как-то получать обновленное название и текст заметки по нажатии на кнопку saveBtn. Заранее извиняюсь, если что-то непонятно. Один из первых разов на сайте.
Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: вам нужно все данные писать в БД , например, а при выводе в ресайклер читать оттуда. передавать между активити при этом ничего не надо. то есть в NoteActivity заполняете поля и по нажатии кнопки записываете их в БД, при переходе на активити со списком в ней читаете из БД данные и выводите в список.

Comment: Что могу добавить, так это стоит создать класс DiffUtils чтобы не обновлять весь список, а только то что изменилось.

Comment: @pavlofff Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, наверное, но что такое БД и как его писать?))

Comment: БД - база данных (средство для хранения информации и доступа к ней), писать не её, а в неё (записывать данные). чистая SQLite или ORM ,например Room, гугл знает все эти названия в подробносиях